# How to handle Abs constraints in Gurobi?

Tags: python, python-3.x, optimization, gurobi

I have a abs constraint in Gurobi. I have look into the manual of official guide. It provides two ways to add abs constraints.

```
  # x5 = abs(x1)
  model.addGenConstrAbs(x5, x1, "absconstr")

  # overloaded form
  model.addConstr(x5 == abs_(x1), name="absconstr")
```

I have to use the second form, because I need to draw the dual value of this constraint. Only `addConstr` can be drew the shadow price(dual value), so `addGenConstrAbs` should be avoided.

My code is :

```
    def _build_constraints(self):
        m = self.model
        com = self.data.com
        P_nm3 = self.variables.P_nm3
        agents = self.data.agents

        timewindow = self.data.timewindow             
        windowinterval = self.data.windowinterval      

        absP_n = self.variables.absP_n
        P_n = self.variables.P_n

        self.constraints.absv = {}

        for t1 in timewindow:
            for t2 in windowinterval:
                for i, p in enumerate(agents):
                    if p in self.data.generators:
                        pass
                    else:
#                        self.constraints.absv[t1,t2,p] = m.addGenConstrAbs( absP_n[p,t1,t2], P_n[p,t1,t2]) 
                        self.constraints.absv[t1,t2,p] = m.addConstr( absP_n[p,t1,t2] == abs_(P_n[p,t1,t2]), name="absconstr" )
```

And I get the error like this :

```
AttributeError: 'gurobipy.Model' object has no attribute 'abs_'
```

the version of Gurobi is V9.0. It seems the method mentioned doesn't work at all.

How can I solve this?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that you also import the `abs_` function - in case you did not `from gurobipy import *`. So you either need to do

```
from gurobipy import abs_
model.addConstr(x == abs_(y))
```

or

```
import gurobipy as gp
model.addConstr(x == gp.abs_(y))
```